# Render component from method passing data in vue.js 3

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm trying to call a component from a method present in the parent template in vue.js 3.
The idea is when I click on a button, the child component is called with some data and rendered in the specific section.

App.vue

```
<span v-on:click="callChildComponent">Call Child</span>
<ChildComponent :tagId="0" />
....
<script>
import ChildComponent from ...

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tagId: ''
    }
  }
  ...
  methods: {
  callChildComponent: function(){
    ????
  }
  ...
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>{{ tagId }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  props: {
    tagId: Number
  }
}
</script>
```

Maybe this is not the right approach...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you @Abregre.

This is how i figured it out

App.vue

```
<span v-on:click="callChildComponent">Call Child</span>
<ChildComponent v-if="tagId != null" :tagId="tagId" />
....
<script>
import ChildComponent from ...

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tagId: null
    }
  }
  ...
  methods: {
  callChildComponent: function(tagId){
    this.tagId = tagId
  }
  ...
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>{{ tagId }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  props: {
    tagId: Number
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nice. But fyi it's cleaner to control childComponent rendering from the parent component.
Otherwise, it's still rendering but without content when you use the v-if.
Also you can set a default value(null or anything) for your prop in your childComponent

Comment: Of course... Code edited. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use v-if in the component you want to render.
The v-if value would be a boolean local data property, that you would toggle with the callChildComponent function you created.

```
<span v-on:click="callChildComponent">Call Child</span>
<ChildComponent v-if="showChildComponent" :tagId="0" />
....
<script>
import ChildComponent from ...

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tagId: '',
      showChildComponent: false
    }
  }
  ...
  methods: {
  callChildComponent: function(){
    this.showChildComponent = !this.showChildComponent
  }
  ...
</script>
```